# rdc windows10 to headless VM using a port number fails

Tags: remote-desktop

I upgraded my desktop machine from windows 8 to 10 and now I'm unable to connect to any of my Vms (hosted on another server) using RDC.

I have one server(Ubuntu no GUI) that host multiple VM's(windows and Linux w and w/o GUI) using VirtualBox. From my laptop I normally connect with RDC using the host(server) ip followed by port number (192.168.0.2:3396 assigned during create VM process) works fine, at that point I adjust network setting(static ip) for the LAN and exit. etc etc..

On the windows 10 desktop I receive and error; This computer can not connect to the remote computer. I can however connect with the ip address (192.168.0.5) no port. this part is fine for existing Vms that have static ip. I need to connect and assign the ip.

Thanks for any feedback or suggestions

Comment: After hours (days really). The answer is simple.

Comment: update the extpack. VBoxMachine extpack install --replace pathtoextpack. Grab the latest from Oracle. You can also check the installed extpack with VboxMachine list extpacks. works fine for all ips and ports